# Updating data in subquery

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, postgresql

I have two tables:

- `PERSON` with columns `person_id` and `total`
- `DATA` with columns `data_a`, `data_b`, `data_c`, and `data_person_id`

Each "person" can have zero or more entries in `DATA` - your standard one-to-many relationship. `PERSON` has a `total` column that is the sum of values in `DATA`. There are currently some discrepancies between `total` and the actual entries in `DATA` where `DATA` is correct but `total` is wrong.

This is the query I'm using to find the discrepancies:

```
SELECT
  person_id
FROM PERSON JOIN (
  SELECT
    data_person_id,
    SUM( data_a + data_b + data_c ) as data_total
  FROM
    DATA
  GROUP BY
    data_person_id
  ) x ON data_person_id = person_id
WHERE
  person_total != data_total
```

I plan on doing this through Hibernate as a query where the backend will be Postgres 9.x.

The incorrect query that I'm trying to understand/fix is:

```
UPDATE
  ONLY PERSON
SET
  total = data_info.calc_total
FROM (
  SELECT
    SUM( data_a + data_b + data_c ) as calc_total
  FROM
    DATA
  WHERE
    DATA.data_person_id = person_id
  GROUP BY
    DATA.data_person_id
) as data_info
WHERE
  PERSON.person_id IN (
    SELECT
      data_person_id
    FROM PERSON JOIN (
      SELECT
        data_person_id,
        SUM( data_a + data_b + data_c ) as data_total
      FROM
        DATA
      GROUP BY
        data_person_id
      ) x ON person_id = data_person_id
    WHERE
      total != data_total
  )
```

Right now, it won't run because of `WHERE DATA.data_person_id = person_id`. But if I take that out, the wrong values get used.

The following seems to work but I'm confused as to why:

```
UPDATE
  ONLY PERSON
SET
  total = data_info.calc_total
FROM 
  PERSON P JOIN (
    SELECT
      data_person_id,
      SUM( data_a + data_b + data_c ) as calc_total
    FROM
      DATA
    WHERE
      DATA.data_person_id = person_id
    GROUP BY
      DATA.data_person_id
  ) as data_info ON P.person_id = data_person_id
WHERE
  PERSON.person_id IN (
    SELECT
      data_person_id
    FROM PERSON JOIN (
      SELECT
        data_person_id,
        SUM( data_a + data_b + data_c ) as data_total
      FROM
        DATA
      GROUP BY
        data_person_id
      ) x ON person_id = data_person_id
    WHERE
      total != data_total
  )
```

I believe my problem lies in my misunderstanding of the [doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-update.html) (I'm guessing the part about the self-join).

Also, any ways to improve this query is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems your queries are way to complex. The task should be as simple as:

```
UPDATE person p
SET    total = d.calc_total
FROM (
  SELECT data_person_id, sum(data_a + data_b + data_c) as calc_total
  FROM   data
  GROUP  BY 1
) d
WHERE  p.person_id = d.data_person_id
AND    p.total IS DISTINCT FROM d.calc_total;
```

- First aggregate `calc_total` from the `data` table, grouped by `data_person_id`.
- Then use this subquery in the FROM clause of the `UPDATE`.
- I use `IS DISTINCT FROM` to make sure NULL values are covered, while only rows that would change are actually updated.
  If all involved columns are defined `NOT NULL`, you can use `=` instead.

[-> sqlfiddle demo.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/fb4dc/1)

Comment: Thanks for explaining each part. Also, SQL Fiddle is pretty handy!

Answer (score 2):

This is ordinary syntax `UPDATE...FROM`.
So, use your last query besides WHERE

```
UPDATE
  ONLY PERSON
SET
  total = data_info.calc_total
FROM 
  PERSON P JOIN (
    SELECT
      data_person_id,
      SUM( data_a + data_b + data_c ) as calc_total
    FROM
      DATA
    WHERE
      DATA.data_person_id = person_id
    GROUP BY
      DATA.data_person_id
  ) as data_info ON P.person_id = data_person_id
```

Comment: If I don't use the WHERE, wouldn't all entries in `PERSON` be updated regardless of its correctness?

Comment: Why would it? You inner join tables, so total column correspond to calc_total column for each person_id that match data_person_id.

Comment: @nevets1219: This query does not work at all. You cannot refer to `person_id` in the subquery. A test run produces as expected: `ERROR:  subquery in FROM cannot refer to other relations of same query level`